# Datepicker dialog call two times

Tags: android, datepicker, duplicates

In my application i have used one datepicker dialog.Which show date picker popup fine and also selcted item displayed correctly.My problem is in call back event it print the date two times so the will be added in db two times when i am insert the date.Please any one help me please any one help me...

DatepickerDialog:

```
 new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),R.style.Theme_CustomDialog,changeDate,calendarFuture.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                                  ,calendarFuture.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendarFuture.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                  ).show();
```

Call Back Event is:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener changeDate=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
    calendarFuture.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendarFuture.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendarFuture.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                Log.i(TAG,"FutureCalendar:"+android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd MM yyyy", calendarFuture));

    }
```

Output is:

```
FutureCalendar:13 08 2013
FutureCalendar:13 08 2013
```

Comment: Whenever `DatePicker` is visible on screen, `onDateSet` is fired. Then when you set any date again, it will one more time fire `onDateSet` method. This is the reason why you are getting 2 logs. :)

Comment: when i am click the datepicker dialog at that time ondateset called two times...

Comment: The log is called two times at that time of selected 13 08 2013

Comment: I implemented your code in application (Which not uses Fragment by the way). It is calling `onDateSet` only once when I click on `set` button.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        if(view.isShown())  
        Log.i(DateDialogFragment.class.getName(),year+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth);

    }
```